# Complex SQL query with JOIN and GROUP BY on 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Here is my table structure (simplified) :

'Video' table contain a list of all videos.

```
video
+----+-------+-------+
| id | title | views |
+----+-------+-------+
```

'Channel' table contains all possible channels. It's a many to many relation with 'video' using 'video_channel' table.

```
channel
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+

video_channel
+----+----------+------------+
| id | video_id | channel_id |
+----+----------+------------+
```

'Thumb' table contains several thumbs for each video :

```
thumb
+----+------+----------+
| id | link | video_id |
+----+------+----------+
```

What i need to get is :

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
| channel.title | number of video | first thumb of most viewed video for this | 
|               | per channel     | channel                                   |
+---------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I managed to get this :

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| channel.title | number of video |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

with this query :

```
SELECT channel.title, COUNT(*) 
FROM video 
INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.video_id=video.id
INNER JOIN channel ON video_channel.channel_id=channel.id
GROUP BY video_channel.channel_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I use MySql

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server - which is it? Or do you want an ANSI answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both, I finnaly managed to get what I want with this query :

```
SELECT c.title, COUNT(*),
(
    SELECT thumb.link
    FROM video
    INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.video_id=video.id
    INNER JOIN thumb ON thumb.video_id=video_channel.video_id
    INNER JOIN channel ON channel.id=video_channel.channel_id
    WHERE video_channel.channel_id=c.id
    ORDER BY video.views DESC, thumb.id ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS thumb_link
FROM channel c
INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.channel_id=c.id
INNER JOIN video ON video.id=video_channel.video_id
GROUP BY video_channel.channel_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a correlated subquery.

Assuming SQL Server, which is my original dialect, you could do something like this:

```
select
    channel.title,
    count(video_channel.video_id),
    _mostViewedThumb.link
from
    video_channel -- count
    inner join channel on -- title
        video_channel.channel_id = channel.id
    cross apply ( -- most viewed
        select top 1
            thumb.link
        from
            thumb
            inner join video on -- for order
                thumb.video_id = video.id
        where
            video_channel.video_id = thumb.video_id
        order by
            video.views desc
    ) as _mostViewedThumb
group by
    channel.title;
```

Comment: I use MySql I just edited my post.
Do you have a CROSS APPLY alternative in MySQL ?

Comment: I had no idea, but then I searched: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

The query to get the thumbnail for the most viewed video in a channel would look vaguely like this, right?

```
SELECT thumb.link FROM channel 
INNER JOIN video ON channel.id = video.channel_id
INNER JOIN thumb ON video.id = thumb.video_id
ORDER BY video.views DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It seems to me like the easiest way to do this is with a sub-query, so you can probably get the answer you want if you join your query with the one above, which should look something like this:

```
SELECT channel.title, COUNT(*), 
(SELECT thumb.link FROM channel1 
INNER JOIN video1 ON channel1.id = video1.channel_id
INNER JOIN thumb ON video1.id = thumb.video_id
WHERE video1.id = video.id
ORDER BY video1.views DESC
LIMIT 1) AS thumb.link
FROM video 
INNER JOIN video_channel ON video_channel.video_id=video.id
INNER JOIN channel ON video_channel.channel_id=channel.id
GROUP BY video_channel.channel_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

But I'll admit that it usually takes me a bit of fiddling to get the subquery syntax right. I rarely get it on the first try.